# How to avoid dummy variable while solving a differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I am new to Mathematica and I want to solve an equation, but I could not get the solution.
I have this equation

```
F'[u] - a y'[u] + b y'[u]/x[u] = 0
```

How can I solve for `y[u]`?

I used `DSolve`, but it gives the solution with `K[1]`, which I read on this forum, as dummy variable. What should I do if I don't want `K[1]` in my solution?

Comment: Sometimes that's unavoidable, because the only "closed" form is in terms of an integral, which is where `K[1]` comes in as the integration variable. (That's a mathematics problem, not a Mathematica problem.)  Especially for the very general form you are providing, I would expect that this is how it must be solved. Unless you specify values for `F[u]` and `x[u]`, this kind of answer is what you should expect.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. To start: 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), since the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) consider accepting the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: You just don't want to see `K[1]`, or you don't want the solution found by `DSolve`? Do you have a reference solution at hand?

Answer (score 2):

If you solve this by hand you get

\begin{gather*}
\boxed{F'(u)-a y'(u)+\frac{b y'(u)}{x(u)}=0}
\end{gather*}
Solving for $y^{\prime}$ in the above ODE gives
\begin{align*}
y'(u) = \frac{F'(u) x(u)}{a x(u)-b}
\end{align*}
$y$ is now found by integrating both sides
\begin{align*}
y &= \int \frac{F'(u) x(u)}{a x(u)-b}d u + c_1
\end{align*}

Let compare the above solution with the one given by Mathematica side by side to see what is going on

```
ode = F'[u] - a y'[u] + b y'[u]/x[u] == 0;
DSolve[ode, y[u], u]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image]

Mathematica like to use `K[1]` as dummy integration variable instead of the actual independent variable (which is $u$ in this example) because it puts $u$ in the limits (i.e. it uses definite integral instead of indefinite). And we know from math, when we do this, we should use different integration variable. i.e it will be **wrong** to write the following

\begin{align*}
y(u) &= \int_{1}^{u}{ \frac{F'(u) x(u)}{a x(u)-b}d u} + c_1
\end{align*}

But using definite integral is not strictly needed. Another option is to write the integral as in the hand solution above (i.e. indefinite) so no need now for a new dummpy variable `K[1]`.

Both forms are correct way to write the solution of course. Notice also Mathematica likes to start the limit of integration always at 1 and not zero. both are also correct (since difference can always be absorbed by the constant of integration because Mathematica uses definite integral instead of indefinite).

This is just how `DSolve` likes to write the solutions. Different CAS systems do it differently.

btw, I do not think there is a way to change this form. This is the default.   At least I do not know of an option for `DSolve` asking it not to use definite integral in the answer. But you might be able to reformat this integral afterwords using patterns and substitutions.

To make Mathematica output a little more readable, I like to do this

```
ode = F'[u] - a y'[u] + b y'[u]/x[u] == 0;
DSolve[ode, y[u], u]
% /. K[1] -> τ
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is a little less stressful on the eyes than the default letter used.

Comment: Thank for the explanation